# Fail to resolve: com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:2.6.1

Tags: quickblox, quickblox-android

I was following the instruction given by quick blox as below:

**Starting from sdk 2.6.1 to add dependency on particular module just add:**

```
dependencies 
{

   compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:2.6.1")

}
```

SDK module automatically includes transitive module dependencies.

But, I am unable to sync gradle file as it shows me the error:

`Fail to resolve: com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:2.6.1`

Please help me, I am unable to start quick blox with the latest version.

Comment: Use proper tag to get correct answer.

Comment: i added dependency [compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:2.6.1") ] in grade file and then try to sync gradle file. But it does not sync and show me the message: Fail to resolve: com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:2.6.1

Comment: @user3386993 - I am facing the same issue. Have you found the solution yet ?

Answer (score 15):

I was facing the same issue. But after searching the SO for a day I have managed to resolve it.

For me, coping the following line to `allprojects` in instead of `buildscript`in gradle worked:

```
maven {
        url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
    }
```

Strangely, You have to include this reference at the app level (top level) build.gradle file.

Answer (score 5):

sdk repository in your build.gradle file at the app level (top level)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

correct solution: adding repositories to the same build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:2.6.1'
}
```